# What is the word for a hard-to-solve solution spoken intuitively, relaxedly and playfully?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to translate the word "khoáng đạt" in Vietnamese. It is translated as "broad-minded" or "liberal-minded", but I think the word "khoáng đạt" is more than that. Say there is a profound question that is very abstruse when thinking about it, let alone finding the solution, but the speaker says it intuitively, relaxedly and somewhat **playfully**, as if it is very straightforward, effortless and carefree.

#### Example

1. Most philosophical works are abstruse, even esoteric, but reading [Zhuangzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhuangzi_(book)) you will find it _______.
2. I find that words like "straightforward" or "warmhearted" is more straightforward than "uncomplicated" or "benevolent". Of course within a mastered hand every word is powerful, but for a non-native English speaker like me, they usually express that the speaker has escaped the suffering of finding the correct words. They feel more intuitive and _______.

<sup>Related: [Is there a term for someone who "can see multiple perspectives"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/125486/80007)</sup>

Comment: are you asking for easy to listen to or read?

Comment: The two common translations you list and your explanation of what the word actually means do not seem (to me) to match. If someone is capable of succinctly expressing a complex argument but with clarity and competence I would call it a _masterful_ work of literature, myself. They are a true master of their subject, able to convey it, without complication, to their audience (which is truly a gift and a talent).

Comment: There is a phrase *seemingly effortless*.

Comment: @lbf easy to perceive and digest in general

Comment: @NigelJ I'm looking for a word not describe the ability of the author, but the nature of the work that the readers/listeners perceive it

Comment: @jxh I think it's a very good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options to consider:

- **[Whimsical](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/whimsical)** :  given to [whimsy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/whimsy) or fanciful notions; capricious

  1. capricious humor or disposition; extravagant, fanciful, or excessively playful expression
  2. an odd or fanciful notion.
  3. anything odd or fanciful; a product of playful or capricious fancy

  > I find that words like "straightforward" or "warmhearted" is more straightforward than "uncomplicated" or "benevolent". Of course within a mastered hand every word is powerful, but for a non-native English speaker like me, they usually express that the speaker has escaped the suffering of finding the correct words. They feel more intuitive and ***_whimsical_***.
- **[Enlightening](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/enlightening)**

  1. to give intellectual or spiritual light to; instruct; impart knowledge to
  2. Archaic. to shed light upon.

  > Most philosophical works are abstruse, even esoteric, but reading Zhuangzi you will find it ***_enlightening_***.
- **[Liberating](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/liberate)/Liberated**

  1. to set free, as from imprisonment or bondage.
  2. to free (a nation or area) from control by a foreign or oppressive government.
  3. to free (a group or individual) from social or economic constraints or discrimination, especially arising from traditional role expectations or bias.

  > Most philosophical works are abstruse, even esoteric, but reading Zhuangzi you will find it ***_liberating_***.
  >
  > I find that words like "straightforward" or "warmhearted" is more straightforward than "uncomplicated" or "benevolent". Of course within a mastered hand every word is powerful, but for a non-native English speaker like me, they usually express that the speaker has escaped the suffering of finding the correct words. They feel more intuitive and ***_liberated_***.

Comment: does the word usually go with proses?

Comment: Do you mean "prose" as opposed to "poetry" or "verse "? We can say "prose", "pieces of prose" or even "lines of prose" but "prose" does not really have a plural.

Comment: sorry, I mean simply "writing work". As in my observation the word usually mean for ideas, as in bringing freedom to the readers. I want a word that has a connotation of playful in the style

Comment: @BoldBen no? But [Oxford in Google says so](https://www.google.com/search?q=proses&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)?

Comment: Although one might feel 'liberated' after reading something written in an 'intuitive, relaxed and playful' manner, the term 'liberating/liberated' doesn't really describe the 'manner' of writing.

Comment: @Lawrence can "whimsical" work?

Comment: @Ooker Yes - I think *whimsical* fits the bill. I'd suggest pushing it to the top of the list.

Comment: @Ooker That's a 3rd person singular verb, not a plural.

Comment: @BoldBen it says [plural noun](https://i.imgur.com/XnzMboX.png).

Comment: @Ooker So it does when I look closer, but that is a rare and specific usage that I'd never seen before. The entry under your link says that it refers to "passages of prose for translation into a foreign language". That isn't, so far as I can tell, the way you were using it.

Comment: @BoldBen huh, it says "1. written or spoken language in its ordinary form, without metrical structure. 2. another term for sequence."?

Answer (score 3):

Insightful comes to mind; or introspective if someone has been pondering an abtruse solution to a question given esoteric context.

Comment: I want to emphasize the connotation of "carefree" or "playful"

Answer (score 3):

The word *[natural](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/natural)* in the sense of:

*"coming instinctively to a person; innate"*

> 1. Most philosophical works are abstruse, even esoteric, but reading Zhuangzi you will find it *natural*.
> 2. I find that words like "straightforward" or "warmhearted" is more straightforward than "uncomplicated" or "benevolent". Of course within
>      a mastered hand every word is powerful, but for a non-native English
>      speaker like me, they usually express that the speaker has escaped the
>      suffering of finding the correct words. They feel more intuitive and
>      *natural*.

Answer (score 3):

With regard to language, the word **elegant** could be applicable in this scenario.

Especially as per *OED* definition **2.a.**:

> *Of language, literature, or literary style*: characterized by harmonious simplicity in the choice and arrangement of words; free from awkwardness, coarseness, or clumsiness; *graceful*, *refined*.

An example phrase:

> Judge Moses B. Walker laboriously, but in choice language and **elegant** phrasing, sought to justify the court's conclusion.

- 1945   Southwestern Hist. Q. 48 463

Answer (score 2):

**readable**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/readable)

> (of style of writing) interesting, easy, pleasant to read

or **listenable**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/listenable)

> easy or pleasant to listen to

As in:

> Most philosophical works are abstruse, even esoteric, but with
>   Zhuangzi you will find it very readable.

Answer (score 2):

Though not a translation of "khoáng đạt", I think you're looking for:

relatable ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/relatable#Adjective))

> Able to be related to on a personal level

For example:

> Zhuangzhi's use of anecdotes and playful dialogues are more relatable than works of other writers of that time.
>
> The use of common words in literature feels more relatable than literature with many uncommon words.

Comment: It seems so. But can you elaborate the definition more? Also, I really like the word "playful". It's better than "carefree" I guess?

Comment: @Ooker *relatable* is when you think *Hey, I know that. I've experienced that.* A similar word would be *approachable*.

Answer (score 2):

Consider *accessible*. According to [Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/accessible)

> Easily understood.
>
> ‘his Latin grammar is lucid and accessible’

Similarly [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/accessible)

If you describe a book, painting, or other work of art as *accessible*, you think it is good because it is simple enough for people to understand and appreciate easily.

Answer (score 1):

**Concise**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concise):

> short and clear, expressing what needs to be said without unnecessary words

Attribution: (Definition of “concise” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)

Or **succinct**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/succinct):

> (of writing or speech) clear and short; expressing what needs to be said without unnecessary words

Attribution: (Definition of “succinct” from the Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary © Cambridge University Press)

Comment: why are there too much attribution? A link is suffice, right?

Comment: @Ooker better to add a plain text attribution because I quote their definitions directly. See [this post on meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5196/71848).

Answer (score 0):

[**Stress-free**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stress-free)

> Not causing or feeling any stress.
>   “I taught in a happy and stress-free environment”

[**Lightly**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lightly)

Both words don't really mean “intuitively”, but it describe the spirit of the person dealing with the problem. Thinking about them, they are also in the same category with “warmhearted” or “straightforward”.